# Spark initialisation failing in dataproc - java.util.ServiceConfigurationError

Tags: java, apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

Trying to run a spark job on dataproc. But the job is failing to even initialise spark context.

When spark context was created with `yarn-client` as master, I got below error:

```
        SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
                .appName("Sample App")
                .master("yarn-client")
                .getOrCreate();
```

```
ERROR org.apache.spark.SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.spark.scheduler.ExternalClusterManager: Provider org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.k8s.KubernetesClusterManager not a subtype
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:239)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(ServiceLoader.java:185)
```

Or

And when I don't set the master or pass `local` instead, I get below error when I submit the job:

```
ERROR org.apache.spark.SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem: Provider com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem could not be instantiated
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:232)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:185)
```

From my understanding, this error should not come up as Google cloud storage connector is automatically installed/configured in dataproc, so why i am seeing this error.

Any guidance on how I can resolve either of these errors and what they mean.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `.master("yarn-client")`, just remove that line. Spark on Dataproc has been configured to use YARN as the cluster manager by default. These are the related properties:

```
spark.master=yarn
spark.submit.deployMode=client
```

If you do want to set master explicitly, the correct value is "yarn" instead of "yarn-client".

See this [doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html) for more details.

Comment: Okay. But how to resolve `Provider org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.k8s.KubernetesClusterManager not a subtype` error in this case

Comment: I don't know how K8S comes into the picture. It is unexpected. Can you share more details about your setup?